# java - Unable to evaluate the children renderer expression Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Why it happened?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, nullpointerexception

I'm working with a legacy code using jpa. I came accross this issue when getting the PersistentSet of EmployeeMaster Entity

[image]

this is the entity that have relation to the EmployeeMaster and produce the error

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "manager")
public class Manager implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -542406941672446211L;
    private Set<EmployeeMaster> employeeMasters = new HashSet<>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "manager", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "employeeMasters")
    public Set<EmployeeMaster> getEmployeeMasters() {
        return this.employeeMasters;
    }
.
.
.
}
```

this is my EmployeeMaster entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_master", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "COMPANY_EMPLOYEE_ID" }))
public class EmployeeMaster implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4956994622541532935L;
    private Integer employeeMasterId;
    private Manager manager;
        
.
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Manager getManager() {
        return this.manager;
    }

    public void setManager(Manager manager ) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }
       .
       .
       .
}
```

And this is the method that call the getEmployeeMasters() that produce the error

```
public ManagerEmployeesResponseModel buildResponses() {
        List<Manager> managers = managerService.getAllEntities();
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(managers)) {
            for (Manager manager: managers) {
                   Set<EmployeeMaster> employeeMasters = manager.getEmployeeMasters();
        .
        .
        .
```

The error in the console only shows NPE

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.openTemporarySessionForLoading(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:298)
> at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:215)
> at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:591)
> at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)
> at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:188)
> at com.compcloud.core.util.rest.management.ManagerUtil.buildResponses(ManagerUtil.java:176)

I need to know why is this happens and how to fix this

Comment: ManagerUtil Does not look like a ‘@Component’. How is managerService created? ‘@Autowired’? What are the packages of SpringBootApplication, ManagerUtil, managerService.

Comment: ManagerUtil is already a '@Component'. @John Williams

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try to change mappedBy with "manager" .

Thanks

Comment: my bad, it should be 'manager'. I edited that. The issue is still there. Thanks anyway

Comment: @desta you found answer for that or no?